# Connecting with datalab via cloud shell extremely slow

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'd like to run my python machine learning code in datalab by connecting to a google instance. Creating a n1-highmem-16 instance with "datalab create" works well and I can connect using "datalab connect". I created a folder and put 36GB worth of pictures in that folder. So far so good. 
Now I'm trying to reconnect to the same instance, which doesn't give any errors and gives me the same message that the connection to datalab is now open. I connect with port 8081 and datalab opens. Now datalab becomes extremely slow and mostly doesn't react at all. I have a 200GB boot disk and 1000GB attached to it. Both are not nearly full and there are currently no processes running. At the moment it sometimes opens and other times it gives the "504 Gateway Time-out" message. So my question is: why is it extremely slow and what can I do about it? Anyone else with the same issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "504 Gateway Time-out" message is surprising. Since you are running the `datalab connect` from Cloud Shell try running it directly from your workstation and see if the issue persists.

Comment: i'm having the same issue. Extremely slow and i cannot connect also, I get the same error message. I'm really sick of GC!